# Do not expand a given abbrev when followed by ":"

Tags: abbrev

Let's say I use abbrev to expand `eq` into `equation`.

Now I want `eq` to always expand, except when followed by a colon (`:`).

The logic is that in LaTeX I do not want equation identifiers (e.g., `eq:xyz`) to be expanded.

Any ideas about how to selectively disable abbrev expansion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either hack the syntax table so as not to treat the `:` as a non-word constituent, or you could write an `:enable-function` that will prevent expansion on the basis of `:`.  This one works:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'text-mode-abbrev-table
  '(("eq" "equation"))
  "My table."
  :enable-function (lambda ()
                     (let* ((vec  (this-command-keys-vector))
                            (char (aref vec (1- (length vec)))))
                       (not (eq ?: char)))))
```

Comment: Very nice solution.