# Do not expand abbreviation if preceded by "."

Tags: abbrev

Let's say `abbrev` expands "com" into "commission".

The problem is that this expands "google.com" into "google.commission".

Is there a way to disable this expansion if "com" is preceded by a "."?

Comment: you can probably do so but it's a bit involved, not worth it. See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14058/how-to-use-abbrev-for-words-with-dollar-sign-as-prefix also read the elisp manual on abbrev.

Comment: instead, I'd recommend just make your abbrev zcom. Whenever you have abbrev that'll clash, add z in front. Or, prefix z for all your abbrevs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this question using the `:enable-function` in `define-abbrev-table` (similar to what's recommended here: [Do not expand a given abbrev when followed by ":"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12193/do-not-expand-a-given-abbrev-when-followed-by)).

My solution is to put all my abbreviations in the `global-abbrev-table` and all my exceptions in `text-mode-abbrev-table`.  Then have an `enable-function` that checks that the character preceding the current word is not a "`.`".

```
(defun my-char-preceding-word ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (backward-word)
    (char-before)))

(define-abbrev-table 'text-mode-abbrev-table
  '(("com" "commission"))
  "My exceptions table."
  :enable-function (lambda ()
                     (not (eq (my-char-preceding-word) ?.))))
```